# Google Glass Heating Issue

Tags: android, google-glass, sensormanager

I am developing a [glassware](https://glass.google.com/u/0/glassware), which shows you cards (images + text) from a list. To see all the Cards one by one you just need to move you head around and the information got changed. The application is some where similar to the [What's Around](https://glass.google.com/u/0/glassware/1692477561182633363) glassware.

I have implemented [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) to get the users current orientation, And based on it current direction the application decides which card to show.

here all the images are coming from the web server so each time when card is selected there is a network call for the images [(Caching Bitmaps is implemented)](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

Now, What my problem is, when I start and use the application the glass got Heat-Up so quickly in less than 1 min.

Could any one please suggest me any thing to fix this issue.

Note : google glass os version : XE22

Comment: Try to lower the `rate` parameter of your SensorManager, using `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` for instance. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL

Comment: well I have tried the app with the SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL rate parameter but it is not making any big difference although it is degrading the UI experience of the app.

Comment: i agree with you abhijit (daya).